# Creating local variables from parameters increases sproc performance

Tags: sql-server, variables, stored-procedures

I have a relatively simple stored procedure that is used to group data inside a relatively nasty view I have no control over based on the supplied parameters. A simplified version of the stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GroupList 
    @list VARCHAR(MAX), 
    @start DATETIME, 
    @end DATETIME,
    @resolution INT
AS
BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    declare @elements ListTVP;
    insert into @elements select Value as elementID from udf_Split(@localList, ',');

    IF @resolution = 1  -- group by month
    BEGIN
        SELECT *
        FROM (
            SELECT
                Timestamp = CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(YEAR, Timestamp)) + '-' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(MONTH, Timestamp)) + '-01' AS DATETIME)
                , Total = SUM(Cost)
            FROM eLP e
                INNER JOIN @elements m ON e.elementID = m.elementID
            WHERE Timestamp >= @start AND Timestamp <= @end
            GROUP BY 
                DATEPART(YEAR, Timestamp),
                DATEPART(MONTH, Timestamp)
            ) AS t1
    END
    ELSE IF @resolution = 2 -- group by year
    BEGIN
        SELECT *
        FROM (
            SELECT
                Timestamp = CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEPART(YEAR, Timestamp)) + '-01-01' AS DATETIME)
                , Total = SUM(Cost)
            FROM eLP e
                INNER JOIN @elements m ON e.elementID = m.elementID
            WHERE Timestamp >= @start AND Timestamp <= @end
            GROUP BY 
                DATEPART(YEAR, Timestamp)
            ) AS t1
    END
END
```

If I run the SQL code in the stored procedure inside SSMS, the code is relatively fast. If I run the stored procedure, the code is between 10 to 100 times slower for the exact same data. Why is this happening?

Also, I've noticed that if I create local variables from the supplied parameters, performance improves dramatically:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GroupListWithVariables
    @list VARCHAR(MAX), 
    @start DATETIME, 
    @end DATETIME,
    @resolution INT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @localList VARCHAR(MAX) = @list
    DECLARE @localStart DATETIME = @start, @localEnd DATETIME = @end
    DECLARE @localResolution INT = @resolution
```

Comparing the execution time of the 2 versions of the stored procedure, I have:

- GroupList:

  - 568 ms average execution time
  - 9 seconds reported by SSMS to actually run the sproc and retrieve the results
  - 355 kB of data received from server
- GroupListWithVariables:

  - 1040 ms average execution time
  - 1 second reported by SSMS to actually run the sproc and retrieve the results
  - 239 kB of data received from server

Why is there such a large difference between the 2 versions? I've noticed the same behavior in both SQL Server 2008 R2, as well as in SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Have you looked at the execution plans?

Comment: @adrianm yes, I have, but it's way over my head. They are different, that I can say. The problem is that the view used to get  the data from is, as I said, relatively nasty.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to read about SQL Parameter Sniffing. http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2012/03/19/what-is-parameter-sniffing.aspx

This might help explain the performance difference.

Comment: So, my only option is using `OPTIMIZE FOR RECOMPILE`? What I find jarring is that the performance is bad right from the start; there are no cases where performance for the sproc is ok.

Comment: Have you considered creating an Index for the Timestamp column?

Comment: I can't. The view that I'm using contains multiple unions; from what I know, you can't create indexes on views with unions.